# Regex optimisation - escaping ampersands in java

Tags: java, regex, optimization

I need to replace all & in a String that isnt part of a HTML entity. So that the String "This & entites `&gt;` & `&lt;`" will return "This `&amp;` entites `&gt; &amp; &lt;`"

And I've come up with this regex-pattern: "**&[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7};**" which works fine. 
But I'm not very skilled in regex, and when I test the speed over 100k iterations, it uses double amount of time over a previous used method, that didnt use regex. (But werent working 100% either).

Testcode:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String reg = "&(?!&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7};)";
String s="a regex test 1 & 2  1&2 and &_gt; - &_lt;"
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {test=s.replaceAll(reg, "&amp;");}
System.out.println("Finished in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " milliseconds");
```

So the question would be whether there is some obvious ways of optimize this regex expression for it to be more effective?

Comment: I had to write the entites with underscore like &_gt; or else it'd show as the symbol the code was for.

Comment: Almost four of us tried to edit your text to surround the ampersands with code format quotes. Just select the text that you want and use code, it will retain the ampersand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s.replaceAll(reg, "&amp;")` is compiling the regular expression every time.  Compiling the pattern once will provide some increase in performance (~30% in this case).

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String reg = "&(?!&#?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7};)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
String s="a regex test 1 & 2  1&2 and &_gt; - &_lt;";
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    String test = p.matcher(s).replaceAll("&amp;");
}
System.out.println("Finished in:" + 
             (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " milliseconds");
```

Comment: That is true, it got it down from 550ms to 450ms. I'll see if we can implement the precompiled pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You have to exclude the `&` from your look-ahead assertion. So try this regular expression:

```
&(?!#?[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,7};)
```

Or to be more precise:

```
&(?!(?:#(?:[xX][0-9a-fA-F]|[0-9]+)|[a-zA-Z]+);)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this wihtout blowing your head with regexp would be to use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

Comment: We are using parts of this library, however we only need to fix ampersands in this case. And it has to accept a string which may be a mix of entities and simple &'s.  - Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the Java regex classes, but in general you may want to investigate a zero width lookahead for ; after the ampersand.

[Here is a link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) describing positive and negative lookaheads

Comment: This is the page I've been looking at when I made this in fact :), took a look at positive vs negative lookaheads, but the changes I tried, didnt increase efficiency.